# Shared Storage AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have done a lot of reading about the sharing of files on EC2 instances and am finding the answer to be EFS which for now is not available in my region.

I am new to AWS and have got my instances set up how I want them with my app running, but have a few questions if someone can help would be appreciated.

I am using logs as an example but there are many other parts of the application that are really centralised and I don't which to lose them when an instance is terminated after use.

1) If I have an application writing logs to the local disk and I have auto scale set up that means a new instance fires up with my app again writing logs to local instance disk.  Am I correct?

If so, when the instance is no longer needed it would delete the instance and local disk therefore losing the application logs.

2) I understand s3 is available but am worried about the performance as this app will be writing logs continuously and has million plus users.

Alternatives I am considering.

- Write Logs to database
- Have a small instance which could be used
  purely as file share and everything sits in the share

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Also this is not just for logs there are security credentials etc that are shared.

Comment: you can collect logs in many different ways. E.g. https://www.elastic.co/solutions/logging or Sumologic or many other paid/free tools. For credentials you may store them encrypted somewhere (database) and check about that. S3 is reasonably fast, for example some AWS services can log in S3 without issues. S3 can probably write much faster than you can generate data. You can easily try that from your instance.

Comment: See best practices for logging on AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/answers/logging/

Comment: I appreciate the comments and something to look at but using existing logging frameworks that write to disk by standard and changing sometimes is not easy.  Also there is an element where there is data uploaded and stored, so if the instance terminates the data will be lost.  So is it good idea to store uploads to s3?